# Parsing a TXT file in Python

Tags: python, list, io, list-comprehension

At the bottom is the way I usually parse a TXT file (works fine!)

My question: **is there a more *elegant/pythonic/best-practice* way to get**

> [line.strip()
>
> for line in file.readlines()
>
> if line.strip()]

```py
### create a sample TXT file for demo

with open('recipe.txt', 'w') as file:
   file.write("""
  3 oeufs
180 g de sucre
  
 le zest de 2 citrons

""")

### parse the sample TXT file

with open('recipe.txt', 'r') as file:
   lines = [line.strip() 
      for line in file.readlines() 
      if line.strip()]

# ['3 oeufs', '180 g de sucre', 'le zest de 2 citrons']
```

Comment: might want to remove empty lines on a separate line as to not call `line.strip()` twice, aka `[line for line in lines if line != ""]`, but your attempted solution seem fine for the most part

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [walrus operator (assignment expressions)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) in python 3.8 to save the strip to a variable and then use that

```
[x for line in file.readlines() if (x := line.strip())]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is considered "more Pythonic" but is the way I usually do it:

```
with open('recipe.txt') as infile:
    lines = [m for m in map(str.strip, infile) if m]
```

Comment: Or use `filter`: `lines = list(filter(None, map(str.strip, infile)))`

Comment: @RichardNeumann Nice. I'll use that in future. Just ran some tests and your approach is faster than mine

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, I recommend to divide the access to the file system and the parsing.

Benefit: You can test your parsing script and the access to the data separately.

```
    ### parse the sample TXT file

def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        lines = list(file)
    return lines


def parse_lines(lines):
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    output = [line for line in stripped_lines if line]
    return output
    # ['3 oeufs', '180 g de sucre', 'le zest de 2 citrons']
```

Comment: Functionally correct but inefficient because you create 3 lists when one will do

Comment: Pythonic code is easy to understand, efficient and easier to maintain, scale and refactor.
Efficiency is important, but effectiveness as in maintainable and modifiable code may be even more important. Without separation, doing proper unit tests is impossible and changing both parts separately is not possible either.